# Compilation (installation) error of opencv at linux Mint?

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, installation

I am following [that tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) to install and compile opencv but it produces following errors after some point (%22 of installation) of execution of `make`

```
...
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/tables.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not permitted
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not permitted
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't see the reason of the problem. I am running it as root but it gives `not permitted error` in any ways. I also changed to different folders for installation, but it does not work.

Any Suggestion to solve ?

Comment: never had such an error, but you should be able to compile opencv as normal user and run make install only as root (if you install in the standard folders, e.g. /usr).

Comment: I get the same error when I try to install on a shared drive with windows . I get this error at 4%. Probably this might help however I could not resolve my problem!! http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=4835.0  However all goes well if I do a `make` in my `/home/myself/opencv/build` directory. Help please

Comment: @bubble thanks that is the same case of mine

Comment: check this link:http://askubuntu.com/questions/235700/linking-error-when-trying-to-compile-on-a-shared-drive

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem as well. Finally, I realized that I put opencv source code in the folder which is a symbol link to another folder.  I simply put the folder in my home folder and make again. The problem solved. I do not know how you get this problem, and hope my solution will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem .... actually I have very low memory on my root file system so I mounted my pendrive to system using "ntfs-3g" driver using this tutorial

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

but be alert don't follow blind steeps.

After this when I compiled files from my pendrive I did not get the error "CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not permitted"

Answer (score -1):

Do not compile opencv on FAT systems, as its fails as a result of not being able of setting the executable bit on those filesystems. Using ext4 should be enough to avoid this kind of problems.

There's a good set of tutorials for installing opencv over here:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/#comment-475432